# angular + firebase auth + material = router crashes

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angular-material

The router is not working properly after firebase authentication. The problem is comming from @angular/animations, both importing NoopAnimationsModule or BrowserAnimationsModule the router doesn't work properly

### package.json

`"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.8",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^5.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.6",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "firebase": "^4.11.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  }`

I'm redirecting to route '/protected' once authenticated with Google, but the page shows the new route component and the previous one:
[image: screenshot]

The problem must be a compatibilty issue between Angularfire and Material Animations: commenting the import of BrowserAnimationsModule fixes the issue.

To help understand and reproduce, you have:
  - [StackBlitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m5gjby) The annoying part is that this example works, but still presents a transitional state where both components are shown.
  - A [github repository](https://github.com/jgpATs2w/angular-material-firebase) with the minimum of code reproducing the error.
  - The [app running](http://haicku.es/lab/angular-fireauth/) from the previous repo.

The firebase credentials will stop working once I find the fix, so please use your own.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should make a minimal working example, not give us your whole code like this ... No-one has time to read all of your code and spot your error ...

Comment: And if both routes are shown, then you should have an error in your console. And I'm not logging into your application with my Google account, and as far as I know the dependencies don't have any issues, you probably did something wrong.

Comment: Actually this is a minimal working example

Comment: No it isn't. A whole project isn't considered "minimal". It isn't "verifiable" either, since we can't touch the code and only have access to minified and bundled sources. But sure, it is "complete", I can give you that ! use **[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/)** to reproduce your error and let us play with it.

Comment: Is your issue in local or in production ?

Comment: Thanks for the reference to stackblitz, [you can play there](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m5gjby), altohugh there finally works presenting an intermediate state in router where both components are rendered. I'm experiencing the issue both in local and production mode.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue on Stackblitz ...

Comment: Unless you're refering to the millisecond where they both appear ?

Comment: Without importing Material Animations it works well. On Stablitz it is a matter of miliseconds, but in my working project and my [compiled version](http://haicku.es/lab/angular-fireauth/) it crashes

Comment: And you have an error in your console ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Eureka! Eureka!

Do to some reason the work you are doing is outside angular scope. So `.then` in `login.component` doesn't trigger `lifecycle.tick`, which will update complete UI. In your app you can see the `login component template` will disappear after multiple `void` events (keyboard or mouse input) because it will trigger `tick` but you cant specify after how may events it will disappear.

This is similar reason for which we used `$scope.$apply` in angularJs for manually triggering `digest cycle`.

The angular 4 way of manually doing `outsideAngularWork` will need modification in `login.component` as follow

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute, Router} from '@angular/router';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { NgZone } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor( private router: Router,private zone: NgZone, private afAuth:AngularFireAuth) { }

    login(){
      this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
        this.afAuth
        .auth
        .signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider())
        .then(()=>{
            this.zone.run(() => { this.router.navigate(['/protected']);
          });
        })
        .catch(console.error);
      });
    }
}
```

Hope this will solve issue on your machine too.

Comment: Good guess, I just have an issue with it because firebase has typescript definitions, and for the time I've used it (including authentication), I've never faced this issue. But definitely worth the try !

Comment: I will open an issue to material, hopefully they have the key to solve this whitout this workaround. By now this is a great solution, thanks!!

Comment: This issue seems to be from `firebase` end. They must use `angular observable` instead of `vanilla js promise`.

Comment: This solution helped me. Thank you a lot!