# Angular 8: Cannot read property 'runOutsideAngular' of undefined

Tags: angular, routes, angular-material

When i run my app locally there is no problem whatsoever, but when the app is hosted (on firebase hosting) whenever I try to navigate to a page I get the following error: 
`Cannot read property 'runOutsideAngular' of undefined`. Because the code is minified to main.js I can't seem to find why the error is thrown. The error is thrown when the router should navigate to a different page.

```
  {
    path: 'manage/:bookingid',
    component: ManageBookingComponent
  },
```

Both pages use an Angular material Sidenav (removing them from the page doesn't resolve the error). I found this [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52166617/angular-6-cannot-read-property-runoutsideangular-of-undefined) question, but none of the answers seem to work.

I've tried using template routing:

```
[routerLink]="['/', 'manage', booking.id]"
```

and component routing:

```
this.router.navigateByUrl(`/manage/${booking.id}`)
```

or

```
this.router.navigate(['/', 'manage', booking.id])
```

locally all these options work, hosted this is a different story..

EDIT: further research may indicate it to be a issue between Angular Material and Router, see this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49271511/angular-firebase-auth-material-router-crashes)

Comment: Sorry but the information you provided are not sufficient to answer/solve your problem.

Comment: @HimanshuSingh what additional information would be helpful?

Comment: At first you can tell us where you're using the function `runOutsideAngular`

Comment: @Batajus as far as I know I am not using it... A search for 'runOutsideAngular' in my project yields no results

Answer (score -1):

It is an issue with the AoT-compiler. It happens in your production builds because of AoT. A fix is to go to `tsconfig.json` and change your `target` to `es5` under `compilerOptions`.

I would try bumping your @angular-versions first, since the [issue is closed.](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/27267)

Comment: Currently using Angular 8 and "target": "es5" was already set